# Nullable Int in LINQ with outer join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ query

```
var categories = (from c in context.Categories
                  join pc in context.ProductCategories 
                  on new { Id = c.CategoryId, ProductId = 12 } 
                  equals new { Id = pc.CategoryId, ProductId = pc.ProductId } 
                  into productCategories
                  from pc in productCategories.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new ViewModel
                  {
                      CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                      Category = c.Name,
                      Selected = (pc.CategoryId == null) ? false : true
                  }).ToList();
```

This gives me a compiler warning at `pc.CategoryId == null` saying it will always be false as `CategoryId` is of type Int and not nullable. But because of left outer join it comes as `null` from database.

If I ignore the warning everything works as expected. Is it okay to this way or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the type of `CategoryId`? `int`?

Comment: What if you do `pc == null` instead?

Comment: I don't see a definition for `g`?

Comment: @juharr Thank you.. checking pc==null works good.

Comment: @user3731783: Note that you don't need `pc == null ? false : true` - using `pc != null` as per my answer is simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This gives me a compiler warning at pc.CategoryId == null saying it will always be false as CategoryId is not nullable. But because of left outer join it comes as null from database.

No, `pc` might be null - but `pc.CategoryId` would logically just throw an exception if `pc` is null. (As noted in comments, it may not actually do so, due to the query being translated into SQL. But I try to write LINQ code which is *logically* correct as well as happening to work :)

Don't forget that `DefaultIfEmpty()` returns a sequence that is either the original sequence of elements, or a sequence with one element which is the default for the element type. If that element type is a class (which I expect it is here) the default value is `null`, which is why `pc` would be null if there were no matches.

It sounds like you want:

```
Selected = pc != null
```

Comment: But since this is EF and it's translated to SQL an exception wouldn't be thrown and the OP indicates that their code works and they are only dealing with a compiler warning currently.

Comment: @juharr: Well, I've certainly seen a `NullReferenceException` in similar cases. I guess it's up to the provider to work out exactly how it's handled - it's possible that LINQ to SQL handles this differently from EF. But either way, my suggested code is *logically* cleaner, IMO.

Comment: Atleast LINQ is not throwing error with pc.CategoryId even though PC is null.

Comment: @user3731783: As I said, that's provider-specific - and may well be context-specific. I've certainly seen LINQ providers which *do* throw `NullReferenceException` at appropriate times.